# Interrupting a simple GNUradio flow

Tags: gnuradio

I'm experimenting with writing GNUradio scripts in python.  My eventual goal is to have a routine that periodically writes a floating point result from within a GNUradio process to the serial port.  As a first step I wanted to simply pause a simple routine  The following code plays a 1kHz tone thru the sound card:

```
`#!/usr/bin/env python
##################################################
# Gnuradio Python Flow Graph
# Title: simpleTone
# Generated: Wed Jun 29 07:26:02 2016
##################################################

from gnuradio import analog
from gnuradio import audio
from gnuradio import blocks
from gnuradio import gr
import time

class simpleTone(gr.top_block):

    def __init__(self):
    gr.top_block.__init__(self)

        ##################################################
        # Variables
        ##################################################
        self.samp_rate = samp_rate = 32000

        ##################################################
        # Blocks
        ##################################################
        self.blocks_throttle_0 = blocks.throttle(gr.sizeof_float*1, samp_rate)
        self.audio_sink_0 = audio.sink(samp_rate, "", True)
        self.analog_sig_source_x_0 = analog.sig_source_f(samp_rate, analog.GR_COS_WAVE, 1000, 1, 0)

        ##################################################
        # Connections
        ##################################################
        self.connect((self.analog_sig_source_x_0, 0), (self.blocks_throttle_0, 0))
        self.connect((self.blocks_throttle_0, 0), (self.audio_sink_0, 0))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    simpleTone().run()`
```

The code above works fine, with the exception of some overflows and clicking in the audio.  However if I make the following substitution:

```
`        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    simpleTone().start()
    time.sleep(3)
    simpleTone().stop()`
```

The result is that the file runs, and does end after 3 seconds but no audio is produced.

I'm sure I've missed something fairly basic, any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

-Ed

Comment: Remove the throttle. You should even be getting a warning that it's a bad idea to use a throttle block in a flow graph with actual rate-limiting hardware! **never use throttle together with hardware sinks and sources!**

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion Marcus. I thought using a throttle was always 'safe' :)  Removing the throttle block fixed the overflow / audio problems when running the program.  The issue with trying to start / sleep / stop the process still remains.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question was also posed here:

http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/discuss-gnuradio

and was answered.  I will share that answer here in case someone comes across this question:

> Your problem is that you're constructing three unrelated top blocks:
>   you have  three separate occurrences of "simpleTone()". Instead you
>   need to create one  and continue to use it, like so:
>
> ```
> tb = simpleTone()
> tb.start()
> ...
> tb.stop()
> ```
>
> You have another problem, too, which you will find after fixing the
>   first one.  .wait() means to wait for the flowgraph to finish all
>   processing, and your  flowgraph has no elements within it to finish
>   such as a Head block, so the  .stop() will never be reached.
>
> Instead, you need to proceed like this:
>
> ```
> tb = simpleTone()
> tb.start()
> # the flowgraph is now running independently
> time.sleep(3)
> tb.stop()
> tb.wait()
> ```
>
> The final .wait() is not actually necessary in this case -- what it
>   does is  wait for the flowgraph to finish, which will happen shortly
>   after .stop() is  called, but if you later wish to start the same top
>   block again, you must have  called .wait() before you call .start(),
>   so always having a matched set of  [start, stop, wait] or [start,
>   wait, stop] is good practice.

Answer (score 0):

This is problem with the way you are crating objects in python. Each time you are calling 'simpleTone()', you are actually initiating a new object. of the class simpleTone. I agree with the earlier answer that creating one object will fix the problem.